# How to add a column to the downloads table in WooCommerce /my-account/downloads/

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add an additional column to the downloads table when the user goes to XXXX.COM/my-account/downloads/

woocommerce/myaccount/downloads.php gives this

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_available_downloads' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_available_downloads', $downloads ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_available_downloads' ); ?>
```

but I need to add a column to the actual table.

Does anyone know which template file this can be found in?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the action. The second action in your list with the $downloads argument (that can possibly be filtered to accomplish your goal) calls woocommerce_order_downloads_table. You grep the creation of the action woocommerce_available_downloads to see so.

In the woocommerce_order_downloads_table callback you see how you can apply a filter and also the relative directory of the template you are looking for.

```
function woocommerce_order_downloads_table( $downloads ) {
    if ( ! $downloads ) {
        return;
    }
    wc_get_template(
        'order/order-downloads.php',
        array(
            'downloads' => $downloads,
        )
    );
}
```

So the short answer is woocommerce/templates/order/order-downloads.php

Comment: That was my first thought as well. Unfortunately woocommerce/templates/order/order-downloads.php is not the template that is handling this.

Comment: Yes per the codex your theme is likely overriding that template. You should never make changes inside the plugin itself.

Comment: I am not making any changes inside the plugin. I have added that file to my child theme yet it is not the correct file for this instance.

Comment: Strange. Do you have any plugins that might be filtering that action?

Comment: good question, I am not 100% sure. I have been brought in to alter the site. Someone else has been building it. As a test case lets assume there is. How can I override it in the functions file. If this helps I did notice an issue with the plugin. this path order/order-downloads.php was not letting me override until I changed it to this /order/order-downloads.php

Comment: FYI, all files I am manipulating I have put in the child theme

Comment: You are on the right track then. If you do find a filter messing with that action you can remove and replace it with your own callback.

Comment: Is there a way to replace it from the functions.php file?

Comment: Yes you can replace a filter from anywhere as long as it exists at the time you do so. Hooking into wp_enqueue_scripts should be far enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200023/discussion-between-ususipse-and-jason).